# Heroku free account limited?

Tags: blogs, heroku

Currently, I am running wordpress as my blog engine on free hosting, but I'm planning to move to use git-based blog engine(Jekyll, Toto) on Ruby platform. Then I see Heroku provides free account features, but I don't see any detail on bandwidth, disk spaces, requests?

Comment: 2022 - be aware that Heroku free accounts will go away around 28 Nov 2022 - https://help.heroku.com/RSBRUH58/removal-of-heroku-free-product-plans-faq

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Heroku provides, for free, a 5MB database

Heroku provides, for free, 1 dyno. A dyno is an instance of your application running and responding to requests. If each instance of your application can serve each request in 100ms, then you get 600 requests/minute with the free account.

Your application code and its assets (the slug) are limited to 300 MB in total. Your application also has access to the local filesystem, which can serve as an ephemeral scratch space for that specific dyno, and should be able to store at least 1 GB of data.

There is a 2TB/month limit on bandwidth.

Comment: This will no longer be available from end November 2022 - Heroku is withdrawing  free accounts - https://help.heroku.com/RSBRUH58/removal-of-heroku-free-product-plans-faq

Answer (score 24):

**Here is the problem I had....**

"We have photo and file upload for several features in our app, but they do not save.

I have read on stackoverflow that "You are limited to 100MB of disk space, but you are not permitted to save any files (including user uploads) to disk because the filesystem is readonly. The 100MB of disk space is for your application code and other assets. The 100MB is the maximum slug size, and includes all gems referenced by your project."

We need our users to be able to successfully upload files and have them save. How do we make this happen?"

**Here is Heroku Support's response...**

"Hi, the filesystem is writeable on cedar, and can handle significantly more than 100MB; at least 1GB.

That said, it's dyno-local and ephemeral; see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

For permanent storage, we recommend something like S3: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Hope this helps."

Comment: OpenShift gives you 3 free "dynos", each with persistent data storage.

Comment: This could be rephrased into one sentence that would answer the question more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are going to come here after me, you can get the hobby pack if you are a student and have the GitHub developer pack, Here are the details: [Heroku for GitHub students](https://www.heroku.com/github-students)

Answer (score 3):

## Heads up: Heroku free tier is going away soon

"Starting November 28, 2022, free Heroku Dynos, free Heroku Postgres, and free Heroku Data for Redis® plans will no longer be available. If you have apps using any of these resources, you must upgrade to paid plans by this date to ensure your apps continue to run and retain your data. See our blog and FAQ for more info."

"What happens if I take no action on my free apps or databases or do not upgrade to a paid plan?

free dynos will be scaled down to 0 and hobby-dev databases will be deleted starting November 28, 2022."

REF:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours

https://help.heroku.com/RSBRUH58/removal-of-heroku-free-product-plans-faq

https://blog.heroku.com/next-chapter

Answer (score 1):

Also, loading your page might take a long time (5-10 sec)

If a free dyno isn't accessed frequently it goes into [sleep mode](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping). After that there is a delay for the dyno to become active again. For me this takes 5-10sec. You cannot fool the system by accessing it frequently because this is consuming your free [dyno hours](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#consuming-hours).