# dashboards in web application vs dashboards as a stand alone file

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh, dashboard, plotly-dash

guys,

I have the task to create informative dashboards for different analysis and I was wondering what is the better option - create a web app which I will update every month or a stand-alone HTML which I will upload in the cloud every month.
Requirements:

- The dashboard must be interactive: zoom, dropdowns with options, etc.
- Must be written in Python.
- It will be shared with 3 to 4 people once a month after an update.
- The dashboard does not interact with database, all the visitors need will be in the dashboard.
- There are no CRUD operations.

Till now I have observed the following options:

- web app with Dash, hosted in Heroku. Not quite familiar with what plan I need.
- stand-alone Html files with Bokeh

Thanks!

Comment: How large data are you working with?

Comment: It depends on the analysis, but no less than 50k rows and 4-10 columns. Some analyses are done with raw data of millions of rows and 10 columns. Python is handling it well, the end result is always a table with a couple of rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked much with Bokeh, but i can confirm that Dash should suit your needs. It is very easy to get started, and if you can keep the application size is < 300 MB, the [free tier of Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536326/heroku-free-account-limited) would probably be sufficient for your usecase.

Comment: I have created a simple app in Dash, and I have hosted it in Heroku - works fine, but I will make it multipage and I was wondering if it works fine.
Have you ever made multipage app in Dash and hosted it in Heroku?