# How many concurrent connections does Heroku free allow for an app Websocket?

Tags: express, heroku, websocket, dyno

I have the following case:
Build a chat with approximately 500 to 1000 connected users for a virtual event (I can't use Zoom, FB or YT), I plan to build it with Express without DB. I was wondering if Heroku Free would support 1000 simultaneously connected users on the app I plan to build, the event only lasts for two days and a few hours.
I don't really understand Keroku's terminology or how to calculate how many Dynos my app would need.

I found something from 10 years ago but I'm not sure if it's the same now and supports WS

[Heroku free account limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536326/heroku-free-account-limited)

And this discourages me more

https://elixirforum.com/t/does-heroku-still-limit-websocket-connections/20029